# Deleting document from CosmosDb using c# SDK

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to delete a document from CosmosDB using the code below but each time Keep getting the following error: "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system"

The document is definitely in the database:
[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
    this.client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUri), PrimaryKey);
    var docUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DatabaseName, CollectionName, documentId);

    var result = await this.client.DeleteDocumentAsync(docUri, new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("/id") });
```

Anyone any idea on what the issue may be?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `PartitionKey` property in the `RequestOptions` class represents the value not the definition of the partition key.

This means that yous delete line should be this:

```
var result = await this.client.DeleteDocumentAsync(docUri, new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(documentId) });
```

Comment: I did the exact same thing. Really wish the MS code samples were clearer!